# Trying to vertical-align text that's in a div; the text is inline-display

Tags: html, css

Currently looking up stuff online seeing how to do it and it doesn't seem to work for me when I set line-height, I'm just trying to text this for the future. My next step is flexbox but I'm trying to learn how to do it with what I have currently: if anyone can send me reference links of explaining how to do it; it'd be great.

```css
#topbar {
  background: gray;
  height: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar li {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=topbar>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what's the issue? your text is already vertical aligned

Comment: Do you want `li` items vertically as well as horizontally center?

Comment: The text needs to be centered to the bottom of the box, not just the center. @TemaniAfif

Comment: @SunnyVaghadia I'm wanting the items to be vertically and horizontally, but I want them to be aligned at the bottom and centered horizontally.

Comment: ok. Let me add the code for you. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're text is already aligned.

But for future references, just use Flexbox, it's a lot easier and less problems.

To the container, give it a `display: flex`, `justify-content: center`, and `align-items: center`.

You can then only give margin-right and margin-left to the `<li>`

#### Snippet:

```css
#topbar {
  background: gray;
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#topbar li {
  line-height: 10rem;
  list-style: none;
}

#topbar li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=topbar>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No, like if I want it aligned to the bottom, it's aligned vertically to the middle.

Comment: Then instead of aligns-items: center, use align-items: flex-end

Comment: So it's best to just use flex for something like this, instead of doing it via inline-block.

Comment: You can still use inline-block, but flexbox is more modular

Comment: Yeah, so with the align-items: center will it legitly allow me to align the text to the bottom of the div?

Comment: No, align-items: center will be vertically aligned center. align-items: flex-start (aligned vertically to top) and align-items: flex-end (align to bottom)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the `ul` `li` at the bottom vertically as well as center-aligned horizontally. Based on that assumption I have written this code. Hope this will help you out.

#### Snippet:

```css
#topbar {
    background: gray;
    height: 10rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
#topbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#topbar li {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```